# "Ronnie's wife keeps his social calendar where she keeps his balls: in her purse."

Tags: meaning, phrases, cinema

What does it mean?

"Ronnie's wife keeps his social calendar where she keeps his balls: in her purse."

I guess it means Ronnie's wife is on top of Ronnie's social life and he is under her control.

Comment: What more is there to say? Your surmise is correct.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I am studying English via a movie and I am not used to figurative phrases. Thanks.

Comment: "studying English via a movie" has its pitfalls. Try other ways.

Comment: Lovely sentence!

Comment: don't abandon movies though - just learn which idioms are clean and which are not. This phrase is not suitable for use around children and the elderly

Comment: See also [What's a man called who follows everything his wife says or wishes?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/103049/4972)

Comment: @dwilbank  - In my experience, most 'elderly' people have a lot less inhibition about using this kind of language than you seem to think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that she controls his social life as a way of controlling his sexuality, e.g. by "steering" him away from "hot" women.

Probably doing both using some device she keeps in her purse.

Answer (score 1):

Another context that might be interest you:

Pets (and other animals) have their testicles removed so that they will not

1. Impregnate other pets or animals
2. Spray urine or other scents all over the house or yard to mark their territory
3. Wander away in search of a mate
4. Exhibit aggressive, lascivious or otherwise weird behavior.

and this is called getting them 'fixed'. It makes them more docile and peaceful.

This technique was also performed on eunuchs, with much the same results.

The testicles are almost never kept (in a purse or anywhere else)*, but I think you can see the analogy more clearly now.

*except for those of certain farm animals, and those are made into 'rocky mountain oysters'